# If $\sum a_n b_n$ converges for all $(b_n)$ such that $b_n \to 0$, then $\sum |a_n|$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers.
>
> Suppose that for any sequence of real numbers $(b_n)$, $$b_n \to 0 \implies \sum a_nb_n \;\; \text{converges}$$
>
> Prove that $\sum|a_n|$ converges.

I attempted a proof by contradiction.

If $\sum|a_n|$ does not converge, then it diverges to $\infty$.

Therefore, $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|}\to 0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$.

As a result, $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n\frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|}$ converges.

How is that supposed to be a contradiction?

I must be on the wrong track...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convergence of $\sum_n a_nb_n$ for all $b_n\searrow 0$ implies convergence of $\sum_n a_n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485378/convergence-of-sum-n-a-nb-n-for-all-b-n-searrow-0-implies-convergence-of) or [If $\sum a_nb_n$ converges for each null sequence $(b_n)$ then $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577036/if-sum-a-nb-n-converges-for-each-null-sequence-b-n-then-sum-a-n-is-abs?rq=1)